# Padding lost zeros not universally in a column

Tags: r

I have a list of US postal zip codes of 5 digits, but some lost their leading zeros. How do I add those zeros back in, while keeping others without the leading 0s intact? I tried formatC, springf, str_pad, and none of them worked, because I am not adding 0s to all values.

Comment: In the future, *"I tried ... and none of them worked"* does not help much: we are generally much better at helping with not-working code when we see the code, some input data, and your expected output. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for some good ways to make questions *reproducible*, which will speed-up and make more-relevant answers you may get.

Comment: That was a good suggestion! Will keep that in mind when posting questions next time.

Comment: I voted, but don't know how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf('%05d', as.integer(zipcodes))
```

Comment: Man thanks! my problem with sprintf is that, it creates a vector, but my zip code is a column in a dateframe. How do I add the 0s back in the dataframe?

Comment: `dat$quux <- sprintf("%05i", dat$quux)`?

Comment: @SilverSpringbb Just use assignment `df1$zipcodes <- sprintf('%05d', as.integer(df1$zipcodes)))`

Answer (score 3):

In which way did `str_pad` not work?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_pad

```
df<-data.frame(zip=c(1,22,333,4444,55555))

df$zip <- stringr::str_pad(df$zip, width=5, pad = "0")
```

> [1] "00001" "00022" "00333" "04444" "55555"

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

As of the valuable comment of r2evans:
My solution is not very efficient and to get leading 0 we have to modify the `paste0` part slightly see here with a dataframe example:

```
sapply(df$zip, function(x){if(nchar(x)<5){paste0(0,x)}else{x}})
```

data:

```
df <- tribble(
    ~zip,
    7889,
    2345,
    45567,
    4394,
    34566,
    4392,
    4599)
df
```

Output:

```
[1] "07889" "02345" "45567" "04394" "34566" "04392" "04599"
```

**Fist answer:**
This will add a trailing zero to each integer < 5 digits
Where `zip` is a vector:

```
sapply(zip, function(x){if(nchar(x)<5){paste0(x,0)}else{x}})
```

Comment: If it's a vector, both `nchar` and `paste0` are vectorized, is there a reason you're explicitly de-vectorizing this process? Also, I don't think this will work correctly, for two reasons: it pads the `0` on the *right*, and it only pads 1 regardless of the length of the string.

Comment: Thanks r2evans. I mixed leading and trailing. I will update my answer. And also thank you for your advice according to efficiency!

Answer (score 2):

If they start as strings and you don't want to (or cannot) convert to integers first, then an alternative to `sprintf` is

```r
vec <- c('1','11','11111')
paste0(strrep('0', pmax(0, 5 - nchar(vec))), vec)
# [1] "00001" "00011" "11111"
```

This will handle strings of any length, and is a no-op for strings of 5 or greater characters.

In a frame, that would be

```r
dat$colname <- paste0(strrep('0', pmax(0, 5 - nchar(dat$colname))), dat$colname)
```